# AngularJS nested ng-repat in ng-repeat (key, value) pair data structure in HTML table element with sort filter

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to print table rows from the fallowing data structure.

```
$scope.myData = {}
myData['Item1']['Period1']= {"Value":1} 
myData['Item1']['Period2']= {"Value":2} 
myData['Item1']['Period3']= {"Value":3} 
myData['Item1']['Period4']= {"Value":4} 
myData['Item2']['Period1']= {"Value":11} 
myData['Item2']['Period2']= {"Value":12} 
myData['Item3']['Period3']= {"Value":13} 
myData['Item4']['Period4']= {"Value":14}
```

I want to print it somehow like this and sort by Period name DESC:

```
<tbody >
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData">
        <td>
            {{ key }}
        </td>
        <td ng-repeat="PeriodItem in value | <!-- here the filtering -->">
          {{ PeriodItem.Value }}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The key is printed out, but the PeriodItem.Value is not. What is the proper way to do that, because i tried a couple of things and none of them seem to work.

Example of desired output:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Item2</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: what should the key value you wants to print..give an example

Comment: what is this `mydata['Item1']['Period1']`

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalcengg/PgbFG/6/)

```
  <tbody >
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData">
            <td>
                {{ key }}
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in value">
              {{ value.Value }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Try fiddle I have added in my answer

Answer (score 1):

when using ng-repeat, "(key, value) in blah" syntax is used to iterate hashes.

"value in blah" is used to iterate arrays

You've defined your data as

```
myData['Item1']['Period1']= {"Value":1}
myData['Item1']['Period2']= {"Value":2} 
...
```

which is a bit confusing. If you restructure it, it should be clear whether the second dimension is an array or hash.

```
$scope.myData = {
    Item1: {
              Period1: {Value: 1},
              Period2: {Value: 2},
              Period3: {Value: 3},
              Period4: {Value: 4},
           },
    Item2: {
              Period1: {Value: 11},
              Period2: {Value: 22},
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, i have to work with that data, i don't define it myself

Comment: myData['Item1']['Period1']['Value']= 1 this is the best i can do

Comment: Then the approach where each ng-repeat uses the (key, value) syntax should be the answer you're looking for.